# Node.js util.inherits issue

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a class that extends EventEmitter and i'm using the same example that is on the Node.js documentation.

```
var events, http, https, util;
events = require('events');
util = require('util');

function Feeder() { events.EventEmitter.call(this); }

util.inherits(Feeder, events.EventEmitter);
```

Then when I create an instance of the the Feeder object I get the following error:
    feeder = new Feeder();

**TypeError: object is not a function**

Comment: events is undeclared, put a var infront of events

Comment: oh sorry yes i switched EventEmitter with events and I still got the same error

Comment: That code works for me. What version of node are you using?

Comment: latest version, 0.10.0 with Express, im requiring the module, Feeder = require('./feeder') could it be because of that?

Comment: How are you exporting Feeder?  What does `console.log(Feeder);` print?

Comment: @janex Are you exporting the constructor in `feeder.js` as `module.exports = Feeder;`?

Comment: its just showing an empty object {}

Comment: ahhh Jonathan Lonowski, you got it! i didn't add the exports thats why! thanks! just starting Node.js sorry heh.

Comment: @janex Yeah. When you want to *replace* the `exports` object, such as with a function, set [`module.exports`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) directly. If you're only adding properties to it, then `exports.key = value;` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jonathan Lonowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15031/jonathan-lonowski)

found my problem. I had to add:

```
module.exports = Feeder;
```

in my feeder.js.